# htaccess wildcard subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to setup an htaccess file to alias sub directories which don't exist to a common location. The URL should look as if the directories do exist. If a directory or file exists those files should be used

```
RewriteEngine On

#Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*) current/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) current/$2 [QSA,L]
```

How can I accommodate for an Nth sub directories? The top level one is the only one which needs to be aliased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash isn't special to `RewriteRule`. Just make sure you don't catch the first one.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/(.*)$ current/$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can this be altered to for to current/index.php if there isn't a trailing slash on the aliased directory?

Comment: I wouldn't. Just add another rule for it.